# Why is "typedef struct foo foo;" considered harmful?

Tags: c, coding-style

In [typedef and struct namespaces in C vs C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240577/typedef-and-struct-namespaces-in-c-vs-c#comment13161479_10240577), one of the comments seems to imply that exposing some `struct foo` is preferable to using typedef along the lines of...

```
typedef struct foo foo;
```

...and then using `foo` instead of `struct foo` throughout the API.

Are there any downsides to the latter variant?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this is implicit in C++ (that is, you can use `foo` instead of `struct foo` without any explicit typedef).

Comment: http://eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4024450/Tag-vs-Type-Names

Comment: @jtbandes So? The question is about C.

Comment: @Lundin It wasn't clear to me from the question body, but the tags suggest you may be right. Either way, there's nothing wrong with pointing out the C++ behavior!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends how much you like the word `struct`.  If you feel your program will be made clearer by a liberal sprinkling of `struct that` and `struct tother` (you can't have `struct this` in C++, of course), then by all means use the `struct` version.

Personally, I don't think that repeating `struct` provides any benefit and I'm happy to use just the `typedef` name.  And because C++ effectively provides the `typedef struct xyz xyz;` declaration automatically (it isn't quite accurate, not least because you can explicitly write that in C++, but it is close enough that you probably don't have to worry about it), I think it makes perfect sense to use the same in C.  The C compiler is happy with it, so I normally use `typedef struct tag tag;` and then use `tag` and `tag *` where needed.

---

For an alternative but wholly tenable view, read the [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst) guide.

---

Note that C2011 allows you to redefine a `typedef` as long as it aliases the same type:

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7 Declarations
>
> **Semantics**
>
> ¶5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition
>   of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body;<sup>119)</sup>
>
> — for an enumeration constant, is the (only) declaration of the identifier;
>
> — for a typedef name, is the first (or only) declaration of the identifier.

Contrast with C99 where this was not possible:

#### ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §6.7 Declarations

> **Semantics**
>
> ¶5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition
>   of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body;<sup>98)</sup>
>
> — for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the
>   identifier.

This simplifies the creation of type definitions as long as you're consistent (but only if you have a sufficiently compatible C2011 compiler on each platform of relevance to you).

Comment: Who wrote that style guide?

Comment: @Pacerier: I'm not sure who wrote the Linux kernel style guide.  Probably not Linus (it says _'Coding style is very personal, and I won't_ force _my
views on anybody, but this is what goes for anything that I have to be
able to maintain, and I'd prefer it for most other things too.'_ which sounds a little less authoritative than Linus would be), but I'm pretty confident it has Linus's de facto blessing.

Comment: The rule in the Linux kernel coding style itself is considered somewhat harmful because it simply advertises misknowledge: it assumes the abstraction via normative typing useless unconditionally. Depending on the audience and concrete projects, it might be true for some *specific* cases, but in general, it is at least false for any high-level language being able to do static typing.

Answer (score 9):

The only downside(*) is that it hides the fact that `foo` is a struct, and not an alias for some builtin type.

Note(*): it's matter of taste whether this is a downside for you.

- It's good for total opaqueness (see the first comment below).
- To see why some people think this is a downside, check the [linux kernel coding style](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) (typedefs chapter).

Comment: I consider this to be a feature. Of course, it doesn't truely hide anything, but it suggests to better use the library's helper functions instead of messing around with the data directly.

Answer (score 9):

On whether or not to typedef structure types:

Here is some opinions around (all against typedefing structures):

From OpenBSD style guide:

> "Avoid using typedefs for structure types.  This makes it impossible for applications to use pointers to such a structure opaquely, which is both possible and beneficial when using an ordinary struct tag."

From Linux kernel coding style:

> "It's a *mistake* to use typedef for structures and pointers."

From Expert C Programming by Peter Van der Linden:

> "Don't bother with typedefs for structs. All they do is save you writing the word "struct", which is a clue that you probably shouldn't be hiding anyway."

Comment: the OpenBSD style guide is wrong on both accounts: `typedef struct foo foo;` can be used for opaque pointers, and is valid C++ as well; while it's true that if you don't use a typedef, you can declare pointer variables without an explicit forward declaration `struct foo;`, you should add one anyway: otherwise, if the first occurence of the structure is in a function declaration, the type will have prototype scope, which is rarely desired -- while it's not actually harmful because of type compatibility rules, compilers may warn about it...

Comment: I find the Linux kernel style rather obscure in general, with zero regard for portability (opaque types are very helpful when writing portable code), so I don't believe it should be regarded as some form of authority outside Linux kernel programming. On the other side of the fence, the Windows API is the complete opposite: it always typedefs away structs. I think this is mainly just a matter of style.

Comment: A more reliable authority would be the MISRA-C document, which is based on actual scientific studies. MISRA-C states that both typedef:ed names and struct tags must be unique identifiers, to avoid problems. They might allow an exception for opaque types, but I'm not sure.

Comment: actually, my comment is wrong: type compatibility doesn't help if the declarations share a translation unit; a simple `void foo(struct bar *);void foo(struct bar *);` will fail to compile without a forward declaration as the two `struct bar` types will be incompatible...

Comment: And what that OpenBSD document is babbling about, I have no idea. I declare opaque types using `typedef name name` notation all the time, and use pointers to that opaque type. Perhaps they are assuming that opaque types must always be `typedef name* name` or some such.

Comment: @Lundin: you can use `struct foo *` without having a forward declaration `struct foo;` in scope, whereas a typedef name requires a forward declaration; however, you should add a forward declaration even when omitting the typedef for the reasons I just outlined...

Comment: @Christoph: gosh, so that OpenBSD quote amounts to, "Avoid using typedefs for structure types. This would force us to add forward declarations of our structs in the header files that declare functions taking pointers to those structs. We choose not to do this."? Sounds very much like a local style rule, not generally applicable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I removed the quote, I don't think it made much sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less a matter of taste.

By just declaring a `struct` tag, the name is also available to be used for variables, functions, or enumerators in the same scope (or even another type, if you enjoy confusion); and users must write the word `struct`, which makes their code more explicit.

By also declaring a type name, you allow people not to type `struct` if they don't want to.

My comment in the other question was referring to the declaration of a *pointer* type with the same name as the struct tag:

```
typedef struct foo * foo;
```

Stylistically, this is slightly unpleasant because it hides the fact that it's a pointer. This hides the fact that it is a pointer; that is perhaps fine in the context of that question, where this is an opaque type defined by an API, but in my opinion would be rather rude for a non-opaque type. It also breaks compatibility with C++. In that language, such a declaration is invalid, since `struct foo` introduces `foo` into the current namespace rather than a separate tag space, and prevents the declaration of any other type with the same name in that namespace.

Comment: I don't think it is fine for opaque types to use the pointer notation either; I don't see why they would be a special case. Hiding away pointers behind typedefs is very very bad practice, end of story. When I write opaque types, I do them like `typedef struct foo foo;` and then force the caller to declair their objects as `foo* obj;` with pointer notation. It's essentially the same thing as forcing the caller to use pointers whenever they use dynamic allocation. You never see stuff like `typedef void* malloc_t; ... malloc_t obj = malloc(...);` so why would opaque types be any different.

Comment: @Lundin: opaque types would be different because the caller of `malloc` inevitably is going to use its return value as a pointer eventually, while the same is not true of all functions. If your API returns something that so far as the caller is concerned is purely an opaque handle, but for implementation reasons it's convenient that it actually be an address, then IMO you shouldn't make the handle type be a pointer type solely because you feel that pointers are an exception to the usual rule of thumb that irrelevant implementation details should be hidden.

Comment: @Lundin: Well, that's your opinion; others have other ideas about what constitutes "very very bad practice", and where the story ends. Lets keep things objective. (And of course, the return value of `malloc` isn't opaque; it's the pointer to the memory you asked for).

Comment: Consider that `FILE*` is a pointer type, whereas file descriptors are integers, and that follows your rule, Lundin. But it makes absolutely no difference to the user whether the type returned by `fopen` is called `FILE*` or just `FILE`. If I wanted to implement the filesystem APIs such that the value of the `FILE*` is actually just a fd (or other OS-specific handle) cast to `FILE*`, where `FILE` is an empty struct, then I pretty much can. The fact that the caller wrongly thinks it's an address is only a minor impediment, but I would not have designed the API that way.

Answer (score 1):

Just stick to a naming convention and you'll be fine.

```
typedef struct
{
  //...
}              t_mytype;
//...
t_mytype thing;
```

This way you'll know it's a custom type. As for it being a struct, just use explicit names and not really `t_mytype`

Comment: Or don't bother naming the struct at all and just do `typedef struct { .. } mytype`

Answer (score 0):

One another argument against typedef is the difficulty it write clean headers. Let's see an example of header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include "s.h"
void f(struct s *);
#endif
```

This header can be improved. Indeed, `struct s` does not need to be defined. So it could be written:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
struct s;
void f(struct s *);
#endif
```

Thus, the user may use `struct s` as an opaque struct and we can keep `"s.h"` private.

Let's do the same thing but with `typedef`:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
typedef struct s s_t;
void f(s_t *);
#endif
```

The line `typedef struct s s_t` will appears in every header that want to use `s_t *` and I dislike redundant code. There are multiple ways to avoid that, but the easiest is probably to get rid of typedef.