# Nullifying a value from a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I haven't done pointer arithmetic in a long time, so I figured I'd try my hand at C and do a simple Binary Search Tree. I can't get the hang of deletion, however. Something along these lines works as I expect:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
}Node;

typedef struct Tree{
    struct Node* root;
}Tree;

int main(){
    Tree *tree = createTree(); 

    treeInsert(10, tree);    // Inserts 10 at root
    treeInsert(30, tree);    // Inserts 30 to root->right
    treeInsert(5, tree);     // Inserts 5 to root->left
    treeInsert(7, tree);     // Inserts 7 to root->left->right
    treeInsert(12, tree);    // Inserts 12 to root->right->left

    // Removes Node "7" from the tree successfully
    free(tree->root->left->right);   // Free memory for this node in the tree
    tree->root->left->right = NULL;  // Set the pointer to NULL

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to write a `nodeDelete(Node *killNode)` function to free the memory associated with a node, then point it to NULL, but I find it doesn't work like I expect it to.

```
int main(){
   // ... snip ...

   Node *kill = tree->root->left->right  // Points kill node to Node "7"
   free(kill);                           // Deallocates memory
   kill = NULL;                          // Points kill to NULL, but keeps 
                                         //   tree->root->left->right **undefined** 
   // ... snip ...
}
```

I think my problem is that I'm telling it that `kill` now points to NULL, which disconnects it from the node in the tree and doesn't effect the original node pointer. How can I tell it that I want to point `tree->root->left->right` to NULL instead of `kill`? Do I need a pointer-to-a-pointer in this case?

Comment: It is really a bad style to typedef structs just not to type "struct".

Comment: @VladLazarenko Is it? I had seen it suggested all over the internet and assumed it was a fairly common practice. Like I said, though, I'm new to C. I had some C++ experience in college, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: It is well described in Linux Coding Style (and applies to C in general, not only Linux kernel style). See Chapter 5 here — http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Comment: @VladLazarenko Alrighty then. I'm not in a position to argue :p

Comment: @VladLazarenko "typedef struct" is not universally considered harmful -- see the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243149/why-is-typedef-struct-foo-foo-considered-harmful

Comment: @VladLazarenko That is merely a style guide for the Linux kernel... in other words completely subjective.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Yes, it is. Style is always subjective. But I can bet my house on it — after a decade or two reading and writing C code in a team you will join the club.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I hope you have a nice house!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want to delete that node you need to set `tree->root->left->right` to `NULL`.  This means that you can't just pass the *value* of that pointer to the deletion function.

You have two options: you can either pass a pointer to the *parent* of the node to be deleted, along with information about which child to delete:

```
nodeDelete(Node *parent, int kill_right)
{
    Node *kill;

    if (kill_right) {
        kill = parent->right;
        parent->right = NULL;
    } else {
        kill = parent->left;
        parent->left = NULL;
    }

    free(kill);
}
```

In this case you'd call `nodeDelete(tree->root->left, 1);`.

Alternatively you can pass a pointer to the pointer that you want to remove:

```
nodeDelete(Node **killptr)
{
    free(*killptr);
    *killptr = NULL;
}
```

In this case you'd call `nodeDelete(&tree->root->left->right);`.

Comment: Perfect! The double-pointer method is exactly what I'm looking for. I wasn't aware & was in C. Does it work the same way as reference variables in C++?

Comment: You'll probably want to go with the second version -- it's way shorter and can delete the root node, which the first version cannot. Also, you'll probably want to delete the child nodes recursively to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: @MartinB That was the plan (the recursive deletion). @caf The example works great by directly passing `&tree->root->left->right` to it, but it fails (memory space not nullified) if I do something like `Node *kill = tree->root->left->right;` and `nodeDelete(&kill)`...

Comment: @KChaloux: The unary `&` operator is in C - it returns the address of an lvalue (as in: given an addressable object `a`, `&x` is a pointer to `a`).  However the `&` in C++ that can be used in a declarator is not in C, so C++-style reference variables do not exist.  Note that `*killptr` must be used to explicitly dereference the pointer in `nodeDelete()`.

Comment: @caf Alright, I got it. I was a little confused as to the use of the & operator. Calling `Node **kill = &tree->root->left->right` (or any other node) and passing `nodeDelete(kill)` works just fine.

Comment: @KChaloux: Yes - node deletion is fundamentally an operation that alters the *parent* of a node, so ultimately a reference to the parent must be supplied to `nodeDelete()`.  Using `&tree->root->left->right` works because it's a reference to the `.right` member in the parent node; using `&kill` does not, because it's not a reference to any part of the parent node at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use a double pointer. You'll also want to make sure you recursively delete any children of the node you're deleting:

```
void nodeDelete(Node **killNode)
{
    if(!*killNode)
        return;

    // Free child nodes
    nodeDelete((*killNode)->left);
    nodeDelete((*killNode)->right);

    // Free the node itself
    free(*killNode);
    *killNode=NULL;
}
```

The null-pointer check is intentionally performed right at the beginning -- this prevents you from having to wrap the recursive calls in null-pointer check.