# Maintaining chain of pointers to address

Tags: c, pointers

This is something of a followup to a [question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670902/nullifying-a-value-from-a-pointer). I'm still learning my way around pointers, and I'm finding it difficult to maintain a reference to the physical address of a struct while iterating through a data structure. For example, I have a simple, barebones linked list that I'd like to delete from via a searching pointer:

```
struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* createNode(int value){
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void nodeDelete(Node **killptr){
    free(*killptr);
    *killptr = NULL;
}

int main(){
    struct Node* head = createNode(16);
    head->next = createNode(25);
    head->next->next = createNode(51);
    head->next->next->next = createNode(5);

    // Working code to delete a specific node with direct reference address
    struct Node** killptr = &head->next;
    nodeDelete(killptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The above shows deleting by passing `nodeDelete` a pointer to the address of the head pointer. What I *want* to do is be able to move my pointer `->next` until it finds something that satisfies a delete condition, and call `nodeDelete` on that. I've tried the following:

```
struct Node* searchAndDestroy = head;
while(searchAndDestroy->value != NULL){  // Search until the end of the structure
    if (searchAndDestroy->value == 25){  // If the value == 25
        nodeDelete(&searchAndDestroy);   // Delete the node (FAILS: Nullifies the 
                                         //   address of search variable, not the 
        break;                           //   original node)
    }else{
        searchAndDestroy = searchAndDestroy->next;
    }
}
```

I've also tried something along the lines of:

```
if (searchAndDestroy->value == 25){
    struct Node** killptr = (Node**)searchAndDestroy);
    nodeDelete(killptr);                                // Still fails
}
```

I need to be able to move my pointer to the ->next point, but **also** maintain a reference to the address of the node I want to delete (instead of a reference to the address of the search node itself).

EDIT: **Some clarification**: I realize that deleting from a linked list in this fashion is naive, leaks memory, and drops half the list improperly. The point is not to actually delete from a linked list. Ultimately the idea is to use it to delete the leaves of a binary search tree recursively. I just figured a linked list would be shorter to portray in the question as an example.

Comment: Not sure about *"but also maintain a reference to the address of the node I want to delete"*. What do you mean? Why?

Comment: Even after your edit, I still don't understand what's your problem.

Comment: Egh. I'm going to flag this question for deletion I think. I tried to abstract the problem too much away from the actual implementation and couldn't describe what I'm actually after...

Comment: @ArjunShankar Unfortunately it has answers, so they won't let me delete it outright. The `searchAndDestroy->value != NULL` was just to stop it from continuing the loop once it's reached the end of the list (next is NULL by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Node **searchAndDestroy;

for (searchAndDestroy = &head;*searchAndDestroy; searchAndDestroy = &(*searchAndDestroy)->next ){  
    if ((*searchAndDestroy)->value == 25){ 
        nodeDelete(searchAndDestroy); // Function should be changed to assign the ->next pointer to the **pointer  

        break;                           

    }
}
```

And change nodeDelete like this:

```
void nodeDelete(Node **killptr){
    Node *sav;
    if (!*killptr) return;
    sav = (*killptr)->next;
    free(*killptr);
    *killptr = sav;
}
```

Comment: By george, you've done it. You understood my completely nonsensical question and gave me an answer that works. I wasn't aware that I could use `&(*pointer)` to go back a level.

Comment: nodeDelete is ultimately going to be applied to a tree for recursive deletion (made a stupid move by trying to hide that in the question), but I assume the alterations to that code are to reconnect the two parts of the list where node was deleted from?

Comment: The point is: you used too many (temp) variables. root is a perfect variable, and by pointing at root via &root, you can even change it without all the extra fuzz. Update: yes the next pointer is (via sav,) re-assigned to the parent pointer *killpointer. The temp pointer is needed because free() invalidates access to every member of *killptr.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, your `nodeDelete` function is working as designed, but you want to keep a way of accessing the next node in the chain. The easiest way of doing this is just to add a temporary variable:

```
struct Node *searchAndDestroy = head, *temp = NULL;
while(searchAndDestroy != NULL){ // Need to check if the node itself is null before
                                 // dereferencing it to find 'value'
    temp = searchAndDestroy->next;
    if (searchAndDestroy->value == 25){
        nodeDelete(&searchAndDestroy);
        break;
    }else{
        searchAndDestroy = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you give the Address of the previous Node that is where the link to deleting node present then it is very simple
code snippet for that:-

```
void delete_direct (struct Node *prevNode)
 {/*delete node but restrict this function to modify head .So except first node use this function*/
      struct Node *temp;/*used for free the deleted memory*/
      temp=prevNode->link;
      prevNode->link=temp->link;
      free(temp);
 }

struct Node * find_prev(struct Node *trv_ptr,int ele)
 {
    /*if deleting element found at first node spl operation must be done*/ 
    if(trv_ptr->data==ele)
      return trv_ptr;
    while((trv_ptr->link)&&(trv_ptr->link->data!=ele))
      {
        trv_ptr=trv_ptr->link;
      }
   if(trv_ptr->link==NULL)
     {
         return NULL;
    }
   else
        return trv_ptr;
 }

 main()
  {
    /*finding Node by providing data*/
    struct Node *d_link;
    struct Node *temp;
    d_link=find_prev(head,51);
    if(d_link==NULL)
       {//data ele not present in your list
          printf("\nNOT FOUND\n");
       }
    else if(d_link==head)
      {//found at first node so head is going to change
        temp=head;
        head=head->link;
        free(temp)
      }
    else
     {//other wise found in some where else so pass to function
        delete_direct (d_link);
     }

  }
```