# Why does this C code treat a local struct as a pointer, when it doesn't appear to be a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

In the following code, "stk" is treated as if it is a pointer. But after looking at it from every angle for hours, I cannot for the life of me see how it is a pointer. Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

```
struct T {
    int count;
    struct elem {
        void *x;
        struct elem *link;
    } *head;
};

T Stack_new(void) {
    T stk;
    NEW(stk);
    stk->count = 0;
    stk->head = NULL;
    return stk;
}
```

My interpretation says that T is a struct, and therefore stk is a local, automatic variable containing a struct. It is *not* a pointer, but then it gets treated as a pointer, leaving me stuck in a WTF state.

**More Background**
This code is from a book called "C Interfaces and Implementations" by Hanson. He creates a library of abstract data types that expose an interface and hide the implementation. The stack is the first one he covers. I'm a long-time programmer just now digging into C, and apparently there's some way of parsing this syntax that I'm missing. Thanks.

In case it is relevant, here is the definition for NEW and the things that new calls:

```
#define  NEW(p) ((p) = ALLOC((long)sizeof *(p)))

#define ALLOC(nbytes) \
    Mem_alloc((nbytes), __FILE__, __LINE__)

extern void *Mem_alloc (long nbytes,
    const char *file, int line);
```

Comment: And you're correct, the *structure* `T` isn't a pointer, but have you looked for a `typedef` that defines `T`  as a pointer?

Comment: I hate code which typedefs like that but I agree with Joachim that is what it must be doing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg OMG, you're right. Elsewhere in a header file, I found this: "typedef struct T *T;" This seems HORRIBLY confusing, so I'm surprised a highly touted offer does it in his highly touted code that is supposed to be very readable and maintainable. Can anyone help me understand why someone would use this idiom?

Comment: is this good style in any sense??...

Comment: @CharlieFlowers I can only see this aiming at making it not necessary for the users to have `*`s in their code.

Comment: Make sure to compile with all warnings turned on (eg, with gcc, -WALL). You should see compile errors galore.

Comment: Highly touted by whom? I'm not familiar with this book or author, but there are a lot of *bad* C books out there.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well, I found some posts on hacker news that spoke very highly of it, and it has a lot of good reviews on Amazon. But maybe some of its choices are more controversial than I realized.

Comment: Let me add something to be fair to the author: the pattern of the book is that each "module" defines an interface of an abstract data type. *Inside* that module, "T" is defined as "the type this module exposes." So it is possible that "T" is the only identifier he typedefs as a pointer. If so, then one could argue that the typedef is not as potentially confusing when used in this explicit pattern as it might be in random code.

Comment: And a little more detail (for posterity's sake): apparently, the goal is for T to be an opaque pointer. And maybe he's abstracting it even further by hiding even the fact that T is a pointer. The clients of the library need to have a handle against which to make calls, but they don't need to know anything about the underlying impl -- they don't even need to know it's a pointer. To be fair, I don't know if I'm completely bought in, but I can at least respect that stance.

Comment: Even more info: I found a SO answer that gets into this very issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10243348/80112. The commenters there debate the pros and cons of "typedef T *T". They mention that it is used for opaque pointers, and some favor it and some don't. Thanks for everyone's help getting me unstuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the snippet above, `T stk` will declare stk as a variable of type `T`.  However type `T` isn't defined anywhere, and the code won't compile.

If it instead said `struct T stk;`, it would be declaring stk as a variable having type `struct T`.  However, the attempts to dereference stk would be meaningless and the code would again fail to compile.

To make the example work, you could add something like,

```
typedef struct T *T
```

which defines type `T` to be a `pointer to struct T`.  I would find this highly confusing though.

Comment: Thank you. As a newbie, I missed two things: (1) to declare a local instance of the struct, you'd have to say "struct T stk" instead of just "T stk". And (2) that someone might typedef something merely to avoid needing the * operator, which seems more harmful than helpful to me (though admittedly I'm a newbie). And by the way, that's right. As I commented above, I found the typedef that does it.