# Error: argument of type "HNode *" is incompatible with parameter type "HNode *"

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I just started writing my code, it doesn't matter what it does because it doesn't compile and I don't know why, it says: `Error: argument of type "HNode *" is incompatible with parameter type "HNode *"` on the line: `getSL(root->left);`. I really don't get why this happens. I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2012.

My code (yes it's not done):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
  char chr;
  struct HNode *left, *right;
} HNode;
typedef struct {
  char chr;
  int counter;
} Symbol;

int main()
{

}
Symbol * getSL(HNode * root)
{
    Symbol * s;
    if(!root) return NULL;
    if((!(root->left)) && (!(root->right)))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        getSL(root->left);
    }
}
```

Can you explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You're misreporting the error message. Look at it more closely.

Comment: @JimBalter Exactly how it is... that's why it's so weird.

Comment: That **cannot** be exactly how it is; root->left is a `struct HNode*`, not an `HNode*`, and the two aren't related so there's no way the compiler would substitute one for the other. The message would be `Error: argument of type "struct HNode *" is incompatible with parameter type "HNode *"`

Comment: I assume this should be the error message, but it isn't... I can show you a screenshot if you don't believe me.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you're compiling with a C++ compiler, not a C compiler ... they are different languages, and this is one of the places they differ; in C++, `struct foo` is the same type as `foo`. But the error message you gave isn't the only error messsage; you should also see stuff like error C2371: 'HNode' : redefinition; different basic types

Comment: @JimBalter Because in C++, foo is considered a class?

Comment: In C++, structs and classes are identical except that struct members default to public while class members default to private. No, the issue is that in C++ the tag and type namespaces are the same whereas in C they are different.

Comment: Yu Hao's answer is more elegant in my eyes, if I remove the forward declaration, will it still work? I tend to assume it will because it compiles but I don't know anymore...

Comment: Yu Hao didn't address the points here. Again, as I've explained, you're using a C++ compiler. If you remove the forward declaration from Yu Hao's answer it will compile under VS, but it's not legal C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use forward declaration like this:

```
struct HNode;              //forward declaration
typedef struct HNode{      //note the struct tag here
  char chr;
  struct HNode *left, *right;
} HNode;
```

Comment: It fixed it. Can you explain why?

Comment: @shoham Two things to learn: 1. how to use forward declaration to define a struct that has a pointer to its own type. 2. `typedef` and structure tag.

Comment: It still works if I'm not writing `struct HNode`. It's ok because the struct definition is before any other code, right?

Comment: It still works if I'm not using the forward declaration. Is that ok?

Comment: @shoham It works because you're using a C++ compiler. It won't work if you compile with a real C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You create a typedef for a struct called `HNode`. Inside that struct you have a pointer to a `struct HNode`.

```
typedef struct {
 char chr;
  struct HNode *left, *right;
} HNode;
```

Types `struct HNode` and `HNode` are not the same type. `struct HNode` is an incomplete struct ( unknown to compiler ). You code would be the same if you did this:

```
typedef struct {
 char chr;
  struct Something *left, *right;
} HNode;
```

In above example `struct HNode` doesn't exists at all.

A simple way of fixing this is to create a struct and typedef separately.

```
typedef struct HNode_s HNode ;

struct HNode_s{
 char chr;
  HNode *left, *right;
} ;
```

Comment: So can I do: `typedef struct {
  char chr;
  HNode *left, *right;
} HNode;`, or will it not work?

Comment: @shoham That will not work because at the line: `HNode *left, *right;`, HNode is not yet defined.

Comment: typedefs and struct tags are in different namespaces so you can just use HNode instead of HNode_s: `typedef struct HNode HNode; struct HNode { ... };`

Comment: @this You're quite wrong. I've programmed in C for nearly 40 years, was on the C language committee, have seen tons of both good and bad C code, and it's perfectly good practice, often mandated by coding standards. It has no downside. And it has the benefit of emulating C++ behavior. There's some discussion of this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243149/why-is-typedef-struct-foo-foo-considered-harmful ... the harm claim largely comes from Torvalds, but he's a cranky ideologue. And it isn't really about this practice, but about using typedefs for structs at all.

Answer (score 1):

The struct you've typedefed to `HNode` doesn't actually have a name (you only said `struct`, not `struct HNode`), and during its definition the typedef does not yet exist, so you end up creating two different structs, one called `HNode` and one typedefed to `HNode`.

You can avoid this by pre-declaring the struct, then properly naming it in its definition.

```
struct HNode; // declare the named struct (not needed with C++ compiler)

typedef struct HNode { // define the named struct
  char chr;
  struct HNode *left, *right;
} HNode; // typedef to a shorter name
```