# Using typedef and pointer in C for implementing a Stack

Tags: c, stack

I am facing problems compiling this code, because I do not know how to work with typedef (but we have to). My method push has item *elem as input but top -> info = *elem does not work. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct node  
{
int info;

struct node *ptr;
}*top,*top1,*temp;


typedef struct item {

} item;

// my methods
void push(item *elem);
void *pop();
void empty();
void create();

int count = 0;

void create()
{
   top = NULL;
 }


 // pushing the elements in the stack
 void push(item *elem)
 {
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        top =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        top->ptr = NULL;
        top->info = *elem;
    }
   else
    {
        temp =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        temp->ptr = top;
        temp->info = *elem;  // here is the error "not compatible"
        top = temp;
    }
    count++;
 }
    // I also got this, this is for creating a new elem, but I do not  
     // know how to implement this method
  item* new_item(int value) {

 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'work with typedef'? Are you unsure about it's usage? Do you have errors when you try to use typedefed type? Something else?

Comment: `top->info = *elem;` `info` is an `int`, but `*elem` is an `item`.

Comment: I mean, I have never worked with it. I roughly understand what it means, but it is a bit difficult to me when I have to use it implementing a method ( in this case my push method)

Comment: Do I have to declare info as an *elem, would it fix my problem?

Comment: If you are unsure, don't combine things like you do. First define the struct, then create a typedef for it and define variables of that type, as separate statemens. I mean, something like this: `struct X {...}; typedef struct X X; X *temp;`. The easy rule about `typedef` is, that it is like defining a variable, except it defines a type: `int A;` defines variable `A` (of type `int`), so `typedef int A;` defines type `A` (to be same as `int`);

Comment: Another note, some consider it a bad practice to `typedef` structs like that. Read this and links there for more on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243149/why-is-typedef-struct-foo-foo-considered-harmful

Comment: Nah, I don't know how to solve this. Sorry, maybe it is because of too much programming, but I am desperated here because of this

Comment: Why is `struct item` empty, anyway?

Comment: @hyde: A variable definition allocates storage and declares it. A `typedef` just defines an alias. They are definitively not alike.

Comment: @Olaf I meant syntactically: You can just add `typedef` in front of a variable definition, and it becomes a type definition (or is there some case where this isn't so?).

Comment: @hyde: Yes, there is. Try adding an initialiser to the variable definition (note that without it it is just a _declaration_ or tentative definition.

Comment: @Olaf Ok, right, let's clarify, variable definition without explicit initializer can be turned into type definition by prepending `typedef`, and vice versa. The point of that "rule" is, it makes it easy to remember which way the existing type and the new type name go after `typedef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the typedef:

```
struct node  
{
    int info;
    struct node *ptr;
};
typedef struct node item;
```

And create a pointer:

```
item *top = NULL;
```

`push` should simply insert the element at the top of the stack.

```
void push(item *elem)
{
    // I assume elem is already created.
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        top = elem;
    }
    else
    {
        top->ptr = elem;
        top = elem;
    }
    count++;
}
```

`new_item` should allocate memory and initialize

```
item* new_item(int value)
{
    item *temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
    item->info = value;
    item->ptr = NULL;
}
```

Somewhere else, create and add....

```
item *someNewItem = new_item(100);
push(someNewItem);
// Later on, someNewItem needs to be free()'d
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But what you assume " elem is already created" is my problem. I do not know how to create this.

Comment: It gets created in the `new_item` function.

Comment: I think you mean `typedef struct node item;` near the top.